# How do you create an onKeyPress event and pass in parameters to the event handler function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a webpage that updates an component based on text inserted. I need it to update the component when the user hits either enter or tab. I am creating a function in the parent component to handle the event, and then passing it to the child component as an "onKeyDown" event. I want this function to take in three parameter, the component to check for the key, then two parameters to change the state of the parent. Here are some snippits of my code:

```
class CardMaker extends React.Component {
  constructor (props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.state={
        backColor: "#FFE4C4",
        toName: "Jane Doe",
        fromName: "John Doe",
        foreColor:"white"
    };

    this.updateNames = this.updateNames.bind(this);
  }

   updateNames(e, to, from ){
    alert(e.key)
    if(e.key =="Enter" || e.key =="Tab"){
        this.setState({
            toName: to,
            fromName: from
        });
        alert("update started");
    }

  }

  render() {

    var containerStyle = {
      display:"flex",
      justifyContent: "space-around",
      flexWrap: "wrap"
    };

    var headerStyle = {
      textAlign: "center"
    };


    return(
        <div>
            <h1 style={headerStyle}> Card Creator </h1>
            <div style={containerStyle}>
                <CardSelector backColor= {this.state.backColor} toName={this.state.toName} fromName={this.state.fromName} foreColor = {this.state.foreColor} backgroundClick = {this.updateBackground} foregroundClick = {this.updateForeground} keyPress={this.updateNames}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the parent. Ultimately I want it to change the state of this component when I hit enter or tab. updateNames is passed as a prop into the cardSelector component.

```
class CardSelector extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var buttonSpaceStyle = {
          width: 400,
          backgroundColor: "#d8d8d8" ,
          borderStyle: "solid",     
          borderWidth: "3px",
          display:"flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          flexDirection: "column",
          padding: "10px"
        };

        return(
            <div style={buttonSpaceStyle}>
                <NameSelector {...this.props}/>

        );
    }
}

class NameSelector extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var nameStyle = {

        };

        return(
            <div style={nameStyle}>
                To: 
                <input onKeyDown={()=>this.props.keyPress(this, "thing","thing")}  type="text" name="to_name" placeholder={this.props.toName}/>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Card selector has a component called name selector that ultimately gets the function passed down as a prop. The function is getting called when the event happens, however I am struggling to check the key state. I am trying to pass "this" so that I can check the key that is being pressed, but e is always undefined in the event handler.

I have tried many different things to get this to work correctly but to no avail. How do I do this correctly where I can pass parameters but still reference the component the function is binded to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **NameSelector** component, try passing along the event object:

```
<input
  onKeyDown={(e) => this.props.keyPress(e, "thing", "thing")} 
  type="text"
  name="to_name"
  placeholder={this.props.toName}
/>
```